# Android Save image after viewing

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I'm using the following code to open the camera, take an image and display it in an imageview.

I assume on the onActivityResult I should be doing a bm.save type command but I can't see one in there. Ideally i'd like to save it as a jpeg on the SD card.
Any help will be appreciated.

Tom

```
public class TakePhoto extends Activity {

    ImageView iv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo);


        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Bitmap bm = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        iv.setImageBitmap(bm);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. Call the following method with your Bitmap (that you took with your camera) and the filename of your choice eg. "myEpicPic".

(I asume you know when you want/need to save the Bitmap)

```
public void writeBitmapToMemory(String filename, Bitmap bitmap) {
        FileOutputStream fos;
        // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to the OutputStream
        try {
            fos = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        }

    }
```

And if you want to read the Bitmap from memory again:

```
public Bitmap readBitmapFromMemory(String filename) {
Bitmap defautBitmap = null;
File filePath = this.getFileStreamPath(filename);
FileInputStream fi;
try {
fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
defautBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);

} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();

}

return defautBitmap;

}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help here mate. Theres one bit that seems to be playing up. I'm trying to save to SD card but it falls over with an error: (http://pastebin.com/FHihS4Wv) I added the routine and I've added writeBitmapToMemory("/mnt/extSdCard/objectattributesID/image.png", bm); to my onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

In onActivityResult you can store the bitmap like this

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Directory");
             if (!root.exists()) {
                    root.mkdirs();
               }


               String fname = "Image.png";
               File file = new File (root, fname);

              try {
                      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                      bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

                      out.flush();                      out.close();
               } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
              }
```